# What are the benefits of using a Miswak?

Tags: sunnah

[Miswak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miswak) is a teeth cleaning twig whose use predates the inception of Islam. The Prophet Muhammed (P.B.U.H) used Miswak in his life and hence it's use is considered as a `sunnah`.

I would like to know some info regarding the same.

- What are the benefits of using a Miswak ?
- When should one use a Miswak ?
- How to place a Misswak in idle time vertical or horizontal ?

Comment: how is this a question about islam? maybe you should edit it to incorperate islam into the reasons

Comment: For info, unrelated to the religious aspects, some of the "benefits" raised (edit: now deleted) seem a bit unevidenced; I've also opened [this question](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/10708/does-the-miswak-help-with-digestion-eyesight-headache-memory-or-illness) which may be of interest. I've tried to phrase it sensitively, so it shouldn't be offensive / aggressive etc.

Comment: @mtk i do not understand your last question.

Comment: @AlUmmat I had heard there is a specific orientation for keeping the miswak after using it, but can't remember. My last question is regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## What are the benefits of using a Miswak ?

Brushing with Miswak cleans the mouth and is pleasing to Allah, and this (in my opinion) is the greatest benefit.

> The Prophet (sallallahu 'alaihi wa sallam) said, "The Miswak
>   (tooth-stick) cleanses and purifies the mouth and pleases the Rubb."
>
> وعن عائشة رضي الله عنها ان النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏:‏ قال‏:‏ ‏
>   "‏السواك مطهرة للفم مرضاة للرب‏"‏ ‏(‏‏(‏رواه النسائي، وابن خذيمة في
>   صحيحه بأسانيد صحيحة‏)‏‏)‏‏.‏

[Riyadussaliheen](http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/9/212)

## When should one use a Miswak ?

One should brush his teeth with Miswak when:

- One gets up for making Tahajjud prayer or to pray at night

> Narrated Hudhaifa:
>
> Whenever the Prophet got up for Tahajjud prayer he used to clean his
>   mouth (and teeth) with Siwak.
>
> حَدَّثَنَا حَفْصُ بْنُ عُمَرَ، قَالَ حَدَّثَنَا خَالِدُ بْنُ عَبْدِ
>   اللَّهِ، عَنْ حُصَيْنٍ، عَنْ أَبِي وَائِلٍ، عَنْ حُذَيْفَةَ ـ رضى الله
>   عنه ـ أَنَّ النَّبِيَّ صلى الله عليه وسلم كَانَ إِذَا قَامَ
>   لِلتَّهَجُّدِ مِنَ اللَّيْلِ يَشُوصُ فَاهُ بِالسِّوَاكِ‏.‏

[Sahih Bukari](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/19/17)

> It was narrated that Hudhaifah said: "We were commanded to use the
>   siwak when we got up to pray at night." (Sahih)
>
> أَخْبَرَنَا عَبْدُ اللَّهِ بْنُ سَعِيدٍ، عَنْ إِسْحَاقَ بْنِ
>   سُلَيْمَانَ، عَنْ أَبِي سِنَانٍ، عَنْ أَبِي حُصَيْنٍ، عَنْ شَقِيقٍ،
>   عَنْ حُذَيْفَةَ، قَالَ كُنَّا نُؤْمَرُ بِالسِّوَاكِ إِذَا قُمْنَا مِنَ
>   اللَّيْلِ ‏.‏

[An-Nasa'i](http://sunnah.com/urn/1067510)

- Before or at each Salat

> Abu Hurairah (May Allah be pleased with him) reported: The Messenger
>   of Allah (sallallahu 'alaihi wa sallam) said, "Had I not thought it
>   difficult for my Ummah, I would have commanded them to use the Miswak
>   (tooth-stick) before every Salat."
>
> وعن أبي هريرة رضي الله عنه، أن رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم قال‏:‏ ‏
>   "‏لولا أن أشق على أمتي - أو على الناس- لأمرتهم بالسواك مع كل صلاة‏"‏
>   ‏(‏‏(‏متفق عليه‏)‏‏)‏ ‏.‏

[Riadussaliheen](http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/9/206)

- *At ones death*

> Narrated Aisha:
>
> `Abdur-Rahman bin Abu Bakr entered upon the Prophet while I was
>   supporting the Prophet on my chest.`AbdurRahman had a fresh Siwak
>   then and he was cleaning his teeth with it. Allah's Apostle looked at
>   it, so I took the Siwak, cut it (chewed it with my teeth), shook it
>   and made it soft (with water), and then gave it to the Prophet who
>   cleaned his teeth with it. I had never seen Allah's Apostle cleaning
>   his teeth in a better way. After finishing the brushing of his teeth,
>   he lifted his hand or his finger and said thrice, "O Allah! Let me be
>   with the highest companions," and then died. `Aisha used to say, "He
>   died while his head was resting between my chest and chin."
>
> حَدَّثَنَا مُحَمَّدٌ، حَدَّثَنَا عَفَّانُ، عَنْ صَخْرِ بْنِ
>   جُوَيْرِيَةَ، عَنْ عَبْدِ الرَّحْمَنِ بْنِ الْقَاسِمِ، عَنْ أَبِيهِ،
>   عَنْ عَائِشَةَ، دَخَلَ عَبْدُ الرَّحْمَنِ بْنُ أَبِي بَكْرٍ عَلَى
>   النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم وَأَنَا مُسْنِدَتُهُ إِلَى صَدْرِي،
>   وَمَعَ عَبْدِ الرَّحْمَنِ سِوَاكٌ رَطْبٌ يَسْتَنُّ بِهِ، فَأَبَدَّهُ
>   رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم بَصَرَهُ، فَأَخَذْتُ السِّوَاكَ
>   فَقَصَمْتُهُ وَنَفَضْتُهُ وَطَيَّبْتُهُ، ثُمَّ دَفَعْتُهُ إِلَى
>   النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم فَاسْتَنَّ بِهِ، فَمَا رَأَيْتُ رَسُولَ
>   اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم اسْتَنَّ اسْتِنَانًا قَطُّ أَحْسَنَ مِنْهُ،
>   فَمَا عَدَا أَنْ فَرَغَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم رَفَعَ
>   يَدَهُ أَوْ إِصْبَعَهُ ثُمَّ قَالَ ‏ "‏ فِي الرَّفِيقِ الأَعْلَى
>   ‏"‏‏.‏ ثَلاَثًا ثُمَّ قَضَى، وَكَانَتْ تَقُولُ مَاتَ بَيْنَ حَاقِنَتِي
>   وَذَاقِنَتِي‏.‏

[Sahih Bukari](http://www.sunnah.com/urn/41280)